# Javascript Asynchronous Database Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, asynchronous

I am totally new to AWS databases, Node.JS and Express. I need to make multiple queries to a AWS dynamodb database (summing all device_id counts and looping through all the bins). I have my code below. The query parameter logic isn't complete, but I can't even figure out where to begin for the async logic to compile and return the queries to output in my API.

I tried nested loops but quickly realized the logic was wrong because all of the database calls are asynchronous. I tried using async.map() but couldn't figure out how to complete it. Should I repeat what I did with the async.map() for the deviceIds but nest it in bins? How do I return the inner async.map() values to the outer then? Or is there a much more elegant way of doing this I haven't even thought of?

If anyone has any additional resources and/or a description of a basic framework for this, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
var getCoffeeHistogram = function() {
  var counts = [];
  var bins = fillRange(16);
  var deviceIDs = fillRange(18);

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    async.map(
        deviceIDs,
        function(deviceID, callback) {
            var param = {
                TableName: "iot-coffeecounts",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ':id': "" + deviceID,
                    ':time': "1"
                },
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#ts": "timestamp"
                },
                KeyConditionExpression: "device_id = :id and #ts > :time"
            };

            docClient.query(param, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                } else {
                    console.log("Querying Succeeded for device");
                }
                callback(null, data.Count);
            });

        },
        function(err, coffeeCounts) {
            console.log(function(coffeeCounts) {
                var total = 0;
                for (count in coffeeCounts) {
                    total = total + count;
                }
                return total;
            });
        }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Promises and ES6 `await/async` are the easiest ways to tame asynchronous code these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping througthe device IDs and issuing multiple queries (Which is highly inefficient) you can use [batchGet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) method in dynamodb to return results for all the device ids in a single query.

You only need to construct the query object with all the device ids according to the documentation and issue the query.